# Passing a Class as an argument to a method that returns and ArrayList of objects of that Class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have and ArrayList of superclass objects and wrote this method to return an ArrayList of one of its subclasses.

```
public static ArrayList<SubClass> getSubClass(ArrayList<SuperClass> superObjects){
    ArrayList<SubClass> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (SuperClass superObject : superObjects) {
        if (superObject instanceof SubClass) {
            objects.add((SubClass) superObject);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Now I want to call a similar method to extract objects of a different subclass from the same ArrayList of superclass objects. Is there a way to generalise this code to take a Class as an argument and return an ArrayList of objects of that subclass?

Comment: You could pass in the class of the subtype and use that, but I feel that maybe you are not using generics correctly.  If you need a list of `SubClass`, then create one and use it.  If you need a list depending only on the behaviors of the `SuperClass`, then use that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this filter if you pass in a class, then call `Class.isInstance()`. This is called **[runtime type token](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html)**. This is a version with streams and the `List` interface:

```
public <T> List<T> filterList(List<? super T> list, Class<T> subClass) {
    return list.stream().
            filter(o -> subClass.isInstance(o)).
            map(o -> (T) o).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If you really want to use an `ArrayList`, then you need to filter manually:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> filterList(List<? super T> list, Class<T> subClass) {
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object obj : list) {
        if (subClass.isInstance(obj)) {
            result.add((T) obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can test it like this:

```
    List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    nums.add(1);
    nums.add(2);
    nums.add(3L);
    nums.add(4L);
    nums.add(5.0F);
    nums.add(6.0F);
    nums.add(7.0);
    nums.add(8.0);

    List<Integer> ints = filterList(nums, Integer.class);

    // prints [1, 2]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints.toArray()));
```

The runtime type token is a common idiom with generics. E.g. [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html#EnumMap(java.lang.Class)) uses it too:

```
private static enum Foo {One, Two, Three}
Map<Foo, Integer> map = new EnumMap(Foo.class);
```

## Update

As per comments from [@Valentin Ruano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415320/valentin-ruano), this is a concise and warning-free stream-based filter:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> filterList(List<? super T> list, Class<T> subClass) {
    return list.stream().
    return list.stream().
            filter(o -> subClass.isInstance(o)).
            map(o -> subClass.cast(o)). // warning-free casting
            collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)); // forcing an ArrayList collector
}
```

Comment: If he want to return a ArrayList rather than any List there is no need for a "manual filter", you can define your own collector. As a matter of fact ```Collectors.toList()``` is actually returning ArrayList instance under-the-hood so you could simply copy the code.

Comment: So, it's just a cast away from the 1st solution? (no pun intended)
I prefer not to depend on this kind of undocumented behavior though.

Comment: Nope, I'm not suggesting that you have to cast blinding into a ArrayList... the Collectors.toList() implementation could change in the future and this  would not be longer true. However you can copy the current Collectors.toList() or its equivalent call to a more general Collectors method without up-casting it to a List, so keeping it as ArrayList... My point is that you **don't** *need* to renounce to use streams for the sake of returning an ArrayList as you answer is stating.

Comment: Looking at Collectors code this could be as simple as using ```Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)```

Comment: Also ```.map(o -> (T) o)``` could be ```.map(subClass::cast)``` and this might avoid an unchecked cast warning.

Comment: Thanks, @ValentinRuano, updated the post accordingly.